# How to inject non-Guice instance into Guice module

Tags: guice

I want to be able to define a simple Config bean externally (e.g. in Spring) and inject this into a Guice module.

Is there any way to achieve this?

```
public class InjectionTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // In reality this would be externally defined
        Config config = new Config("a", "b");

        AbstractModule module = new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Config.class).toInstance(config);
            }
        };

        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        Thing instance = injector.getInstance(Thing.class);
    }

    static class Thing {
        final Config config;

        public Thing(Config config) {
            this.config = config;
        }
    }

    static class Config {
        final String a, b;

        public Config(String a, String b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }
    }
}
```

The test fails with:

> com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:
>
> 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in guice.InjectionTest$Thing. > Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
>     at guice.InjectionTest$Thing.class(Unknown Source)
>     while locating guice.InjectionTest$Thing
>
> 1 error

Answer (score 5):

You have an answer in the error message.

> Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with
>   @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.

Add `@Inject` annotation to `Thing` constructor

```
@Inject
public Thing(Config config) {
  this.config = config;
}
```